Suppose $A$ is an infinitely long binary string. Does $A$ contain a square, $XX,$ where $\vert X\vert =k,$ for infinitely many $k?$

Suppose $A$ is an infinitely long binary string. Does $A$ contain a
square, $XX,$ where $\vert X\vert =k,$ for infinitely many $k?$

Proof by contradiction or finding a counter-example is probably the way to go.

Please clarify your question.

I think its perfectly clear

this paper claims to construct an infinite binary string with no squares of length $≥4$.  I have not checked it.

@lulu IMHO you should post it as answer.

@JeanAbouSamra  If I had checked the result, I would.  As it is, I just noted the claim in the abstract.  If the OP confirms the construction, they can post the link themselves and thereby close the question.

Here's another paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316574900417) that explicitly states your question as Conjecture A and disproves it.

This paper (On Repetitions of Blocks in Binary Sequences (1975) by F. M. DEKKINNG and communicated by Paul Erdos ) is the oldest one I could find that answers my question. Other papers can be found in links in the comments or via google search.
Edit: this paper was released a year earlier.
